# Is there any way to see query profile for failed queries?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to identify the scan result and statistics for one of my failed query in Snowflake. But Query profile of the query seems **Blank**.
Can somebody please help and let me know if there is a way to see QueryProfile of failed queries?

Comment: Present much more information about what you're trying to do, how you're trying to do it, and how it's going wrong.

Answer (score 4):

If a query fails during execution, you should generally see the profile. I can think of two scenarios where you wouldn't:

1. The query failed during compilation, meaning it never started running on the warehouse
2. The query failed in a way that made it impossible to save the profiling information

Another point is that sometimes with very complex execution profiles, the query profile may take a bit to load. Either way, there are no special hidden controls that would make the profile visible if it's not currently being shown.